# Angular 7 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

Tags: angular, asynchronous, pipe

Hi am very new to angular was trying to implement autocomplete using customfilters was getting this error related to pipe was not able find a solution from past 3 days.. can someone pls help me with this

```html
<mat-form-field class="col-12 col-sm-6">
    <mat-label class="padding">Units</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="unit" [(value)]="selected"  required style="padding-left: 10px;">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let list of unitsList | async" [value]="list.codename">{{list.codevalue}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf="getvalue1.unit.errors">{{getunitErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

my ts file:

```js
 ngOnInit() {
    //
    this.projectservice.getInventoryProjectsList().subscribe(
      data => {
       this.projectsList2 = data;
      }
    );

    // for inventory dropdown
    this.inventory.getInvDropdown().subscribe(
      data => {

        this.unitsList = data['units'];
        console.log(this.unitsList);
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-string-literal

      }
    );
    this.formBuilderOnDemand();
    this.filter();

  }
  // // for filter
  filter() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.addInventoryForm.value.itemName.valueChanges
    .pipe(    // Error line 
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
  }

  // for search in item name
  private _filter(value: any): any[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.materialList.filter(list => list.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
```

Comment: Error is on which line? Always post full error output and traceback. Also post code mentioned in that traceback.

Comment: @Frieder i have  commented the error line of code

Comment: Whats the error you get

Comment: Can you add the definition of `addInventoryForm` to your code please

Answer (score 1):

You're using `unitsList | async` on your HTML, but `unitsList` is already an Array, the [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) is intended to be used on asynchronous types (i.e. `Observable` or `Promise`)

Not sure this will fully make your code work but I think this will fix the error you're getting right now

**EDIT**

From your edit, you´re trying to subscribe to *(what I think is)* the value of a `FormControl`, you need to subscribe to the FormControl's value changes.

```js
this.myForm.get('myFormControl').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
  //Do something when "myFormControl" value changes
});
```

Comment: remove `| async` from the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Did you import startWith from RxJS?

```
import {map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

You have to add it to your ts file.

Answer (score 0):

Use mat-autocomplete directive

https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input tabindex="-1"
    type="text"
    matInput
    placeholder="Search..."
    #unitsInput
    [formControl]="unit"
    [matAutocomplete]="unitAuto">
    <mat-autocomplete
    autoFocus=false
    (optionSelected)="utitSelected($event)"
    #unitAuto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option
        [attr.disabled]="false"
        *ngFor="let list of filteredOptions | async"
        [value]="list.codename"
        >
            <span class="options_span">
                {{list.codename}}
            </span>
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

**ts file:**

```
.....
@ViewChild('chipInput') chipInput: { nativeElement: { value: string; }; };

unit = new FormControl();

.....

ngOnInit() {
    //
    this.projectservice.getInventoryProjectsList().subscribe(
    data => {
    this.projectsList2 = data;
    }
    );

    // for inventory dropdown
    this.inventory.getInvDropdown().subscribe(
    data => {

        this.unitsList = data['units'];
        console.log(this.unitsList);
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-string-literal

    }
    );
    this.formBuilderOnDemand();
    this.filteredOptions = this.unit.valueChanges
        .pipe(    // Error line 
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
        );
}

    // for search in item name
private _filter(value: any): any[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.unitsList.filter(list => list.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
}
    }


        utitSelected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
        this.unitsInput.nativeElement.value = '';
        this.unit.setValue('');
    }
```